# GitHub: reset a fork to the upstream status

Tags: github

I created a fork of a repo.
I have done some messy work and want to reset the fork. So I fetched the remote with:

```
 git fetch XYZ_MASTER
```

And then I performed:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Problem is that now, when I check the status via `git status` it shows:

```
On branch master

Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 39 and 3 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
```

How can I solve this? I'm not sure what to do next. I tried to pull the changes from my fork but it didn't help and resulted in `merge` conflicts.

Answer (score 4):

I had some issues with these instructions, but was able to make it work by doing:

```
git checkout master
git fetch upstream
git reset --hard upstream/master
git push --force
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have forked a repo, then "`origin`" references your own repo (the GitHub fork of the original GitHub repo)

If `XYZ_MASTER` is the remote referencing the original GitHub repo (do a `git remote -v` to be sure), then a better way to reset your fork would be:

```
git checkout master
git fetch XYZ_MASTER
git reset --hard XYZ_MASTER/master
git push --force
```